# Creating A button on my Webform to open up my CrystalReportViewer

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

I've just started coding(im using visual studio 2012 right now) and one of my task right now is to open up the crystalreportviewer from a webform onclick a button, I have created the webform/db/crystalreport but i just dont know how to open up the crystalreportviewer on my browser and as well as linking it to the button onclick.

I have went through many tutorials/videos/blogs but still do not understand how to solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
        cryRpt.Load("YOURCRYSTALREPORTFILE");
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt;


    }
```

i have figured out how to create a button and onclick it would open up the crystal report by loading